# Can not delete the record from search page

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have an index page in my application. When I am deleting a record from the index page it is being deleted. But when I am deleting any record from the Search page(showing same data as index page), I cannot delete the record. It shows the error :

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Delete(Int32)' in 'JNN.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

Here is my controller which is working well for the index page:

```
  public ActionResult Delete(int id)
  {
      ComplainTable et = oe.ComplainTables.Find(id);
      oe.ComplainTables.Remove(et);
      oe.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
```

Here is the ActionLink for search page:

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Update", "Update", new { id = item.ComplainId }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ComplainId })
</td>
```

Here is the ActionLink for Index Page:

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Update", "Update", new { id = item.ComplainId }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ComplainId })
</td>
```

Both the page has the same code, but why I am getting the error on deleting the record of the search page?

Comment: Is the controller the same in both questions?

Comment: Yes! For both actions controller is the same.

Comment: Try setting nullable int parameter: `public ActionResult Delete(int? id)`, or set default value as optional parameter like `public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)`. Also I want to see how `ActionLink`s are generated in search page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `item.ComplaintID` seems to be null when passed from `ActionLink` in search page. You should use nullable argument like this:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        // return view
    }

    ComplainTable et = oe.ComplainTables.Find(id);
    oe.ComplainTables.Remove(et);
    oe.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Or setting default value with null-coalescing operator from `ActionLink`:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    if (id == 0)
    {
        // return view
    }

    ComplainTable et = oe.ComplainTables.Find(id);
    oe.ComplainTables.Remove(et);
    oe.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ComplainId ?? 0 })
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not supplying `ComplainId` in the search page. `ComplainId` must be `null` in the search page. Please check what the id is for the above links in the search page using the Chrome developer tool (F12).